# нужно на canvas нарисовать прямоугольник с круглыми краями

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, canvas

[image: индикатор]

помогите на canvas нарисовать, желательно такого цвета

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var cnv = document.getElementById('cnv');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(100, 50, 3, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = '#00BFF5';
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#00BFF5';
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 35;
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
   
<canvas id="cnv" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```